# Restrict what jobs can run on Jenkins Slave, via SSH Creds in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a global jenkins master, that many teams manage and use. We have our own jenkins slave, that we manage and as our own tools on it. I'd like to restrict the use of that slave, to only our jobs leveraging pipeline as code. The below is some sudo code of what I want to achieve. My question, is this possible or will this work?

```
 UserPass = getCredsFromCredStore
 withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
     node ('myNode')  { //need to dynamically configure this
        //do Stuff
     }

}
```

The `withCredentials` will pass SSH credentials to the node inside the scope of running  inside the block. Therefore, other team members, can only run jobs on this slave, if they know the ssh details, which we will manage in our external credentials store.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do what you want is with the Folders Plus plugin, which is a cloudbees plugin, and not free. You can restrict a slave to only be used by a specific folder of jobs.

You can't use code in a job to restrict the slave, because someone could just write other code in another job that doesn't have the same restrictions.

Comment: Someone mentioned to me, I may be able to achieve this with the role strategy plugin, and create a slave role.